# What is an elegant way to select all non-None elements from parameters and place them in a python dictionary?

Tags: python

```
def function(varone=None, vartwo=None, varthree=None):
     values = {}
            if var1 is not None:   
                    values['var1'] = varone
            if var2 is not None:
                    values['var2'] = vartwo
            if var3 is not None:
                    values['var3'] = varthree
            if not values:
                    raise Exception("No values provided")
```

Can someone suggest a more elegant, pythonic way to accomplish taking placing non-null named variables and placing them in a dictionary? I do not want the values to be passed in as a dictionary. The key names of "values" are important and must be as they are. The value of "varone" must go into var1, "vartwo" must go into var2 and so on; Thanks.

Comment: You can pass your parameters rather as `*kwarg` in your function.

Comment: By the way, this seems like kind of an odd thing to raise an exception for in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `kwargs`:

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
    values = {}
    for k in kwargs:
        if kwargs[k] is not None:
            values[k] = kwargs[k]
    if not values:
        raise Exception("No values provided")
    return values

>>> function(varone=None, vartwo="fish", varthree=None)
{'vartwo': 'fish'}
```

With this syntax, Python removes the need to explicitly specify any argument list, and allows functions to handle any old keyword arguments they want.

If you're specifically looking for keys `var1` etc instead of `varone` you just modify the function call:

```
>>> function(var1=None, var2="fish", var3=None)
{'var2': 'fish'}
```

If you want to be REALLY slick, you can use list comprehensions:

```
def function(**kwargs):
    values = dict([i for i in kwargs.iteritems() if i[1] != None])
    if not values:
        raise Exception("foo")
    return values
```

Again, you'll have to alter your parameter names to be consistent with your output keys.

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension (or it could be a dict comprehension in newer versions of Python)

Answer (score 4):

Use `**kwargs`. Example:

```
def function(**kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        raise Exception("No values provided")
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print("%s: %r") % (k, v)
```

If you really are going to call `function` with `None` arguments, you can strip them out:

```
def function(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v is None:
            del kwargs[k]
    if not kwargs:
        raise Exception("No values provided")
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print("%s: %r") % (k, v)
```

Obviously you could call the dict `values` instead, but `kwargs` is the conventional name, and will make your code more intelligible to other people.

Comment: It's probably cleaner to just skip printing the `None`s, rather than removing them from the dictionary beforehand.

Comment: But to work the same way as the function in the question is intended to, it needs to raise an exception if there are no non-None arguments ...

Comment: OK, well, you could just keep a boolean flag indicating whether any non-`None` items were encountered (and printed), and raise the exception if the flag is not set after the loop.

Comment: I suppose ... but the print loop at the end is really just so that the function does something, anything. Actually answering the question is better solved like this, I think.

Comment: Why does the function have to do something? And in any case, it is already doing something, namely filtering the arguments. I do not agree that this is a better answer to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18652/discussion-between-david-zaslavsky-and-zero-piraeus)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can pass all those values inside a `keyword argument`: -

```
def function(*nkwargs, **kwargs):
    values = {}

    for k in kwargs:
        if kwargs[k] is not None:
            values[k] = kwargs[k]
    if not values:
        raise Exception("No values")
    print values

try:
    function()
except Exception, e:
    print e

function(varOne=123, varTwo=None)
function(varOne=123, varTwo=234)
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
No values
{'varOne': 123}
{'varOne': 123, 'varTwo': 234}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function as usual, but accept as `**kwargs`. Then filter them:

```
def fn(**kwargs):
    items = {'var%s' % i: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(items)}

fn(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

if you need a specific set of names, then make a dict of names:

```
    names = dict(zip('varOne varTwo varThree'.split(), range(1, 4)))
```

walk over this dict and check if the var is in kwargs:

```
items = {'var%s' % k: kwargs[v] for k, v in names.items() if v in kwargs}
```

Comment: Right. In the second examlpe I use list comprehensions.